# initiate class parameters after initiating two members of class

Tags: c#, .net, class, setter

at first i apologize if its a silly question. I'm new in .net.

I have a mobile class like this:

```
    public class Mobile
{
    private string region;
    private string number;
    private bool regionIsValid;
    private bool numberContentIsValid;
    private string internationalNumber;

    public string Region
    {
        set { region = value.ToUpper(); ConvertNumber(); }
        get { return region; }
    }
    public string Number
    {
        set { number = value; ConvertNumber(); }
        get { return number; }
    }
    public Interface Reason
    {
        set { reason = value; }
        get { return reason; }
    }
    public bool NumberContentIsValid
    {
        set { numberContentIsValid = value; }
        get { return numberContentIsValid; }
    }
    public string InternationalNumber
    {
        set { internationalNumber = value; }
        get { return internationalNumber; }
    }

    public void ConvertNumber()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            if (Number == null || Region == null || DoesNumberContentValid() == false || NumberContentIsValid == false)
                return;

            var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
            var phone = phoneUtil.Parse(Number, Region);
            InternationalNumber = phoneUtil.Format(phone, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

            Log.GetLogger().Info(Format.CreateLogMessage("converting mobile number completed successfully.", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.GetLogger().Error(Format.CreateLogMessage(ex.ToString(), sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            return;
        }

    }
    public bool DoesNumberContentValid()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var len = new Regex(@"^.{2,20}$"); //length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20
        var digit = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*$"); //a string consisting only of numbers

        if (number.StartsWith(@"+") == true) number = number.Substring(1);
        number = number.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

        try
        {
            if (!len.IsMatch(Number))
            {
                NumberContentIsValid = false;
                Reason = new Interface("G00005");
            }
            else if (!digit.IsMatch(Number))
            {
                NumberContentIsValid = false;
                Reason = new Interface("G00005");
            }
            else if (Region != "IR")
            {
                NumberContentIsValid = false;
                Reason = new Interface("G00005");
            }
            else
            {
                var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
                var mobile = phoneUtil.Parse(Number, Region);
                if (phoneUtil.IsValidNumber(mobile) != true)
                {
                    NumberContentIsValid = false;
                    Reason = new Interface("G00005");
                }
                else if (phoneUtil.GetNumberType(mobile).ToString() != "MOBILE")
                {
                    NumberContentIsValid = false;
                    Reason = new Interface("G00005");
                }
                else
                    NumberContentIsValid = true;
            }

            Log.GetLogger().Info(Format.CreateLogMessage("mobile content validation completed successfully.", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Reason = new Interface("G00001", ex.Message);
            Log.GetLogger().Error(Format.CreateLogMessage(ex.ToString(), sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

i want to initiate the `internationalNumber` if `Number` and `Region` both are available. please take look at my `convertnumber()` method:

```
        public void ConvertNumber()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            if (Number == null || Region == null || DoesNumberContentValid() == false || NumberContentIsValid == false)
                return;

            var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
            var phone = phoneUtil.Parse(Number, Region);
            InternationalNumber = phoneUtil.Format(phone, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

            Log.GetLogger().Info(Format.CreateLogMessage("converting mobile number completed successfully.", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.GetLogger().Error(Format.CreateLogMessage(ex.ToString(), sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
            return;
        }

    }
```

in order to do this i use the `Number` and `Region` property setter like this:

```
public string Region
{
    set { region = value.ToUpper(); ConvertNumber(); }
    get { return region; }
}
public string Number
{
    set { number = value; ConvertNumber(); }
    get { return number; }
}
```

it works. but it might causes unexpected errors(you realize if take look at my `DoesNumberContentValid()` method. tips: i have to use the `number` instead `Number`)
now i wonder is there better way to do it? (obliviously i cant use class contractor because i cant initiate both parameters at a same time. )

Thank you.

Comment: IS the international number property always in relation to the other two properties? Are you sure you want to allow the user to set the international number property separately?

Comment: Thanks dear @ Maor Veitsman. yes the international number always in relation to the other two properties and i want to et the international number property separately.

Comment: Just to be sure, the InternationalNumber property should have a private setter, right?

Comment: no. it has a public setter.(i can set the InternationalNumber any where in my project.)

Comment: If the international number has been set and both the region and number has been set as well, what is the international number that should be returned?

Comment: no. let me explain it again. number is the user input.(its a mobile number) but i save it in a database in international format. this is my mobile number: 9111111111 and this is my international number: +98 911 111 1111(some how it contain the number value and region)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
public string InternationalNumber
{
    set { internationalNumber = value; }
    get { return internationalNumber ?? CalcInternationalNumber(); }
}
```

And the function CalcInternationalNumber:

```
public string CalcInternationalNumber()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    try
    {
        if (Number == null || Region == null || DoesNumberContentValid() == false || NumberContentIsValid == false)
            return null;

        var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
        var phone = phoneUtil.Parse(Number, Region);
        var intNum = phoneUtil.Format(phone, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

        Log.GetLogger().Info(Format.CreateLogMessage("converting mobile number completed successfully.", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
        return intNum;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.GetLogger().Error(Format.CreateLogMessage(ex.ToString(), sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
        return null;
    }

}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.